# @Html.Action is raising "HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete. "

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc5.2.2. web application, and i have the following code inside my view:-

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Skill")
```

which will call the following Action method:-

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string filter = null, int page = 1, int pageSize = 20, string sort = "Name", string sortdir = "DESC")
        {


            var records = new PagedList<Skill>();
            ViewBag.filter = filter;
            records.Content = await skillRepository.GetSkillForGrid(filter, page, pageSize, sort, sortdir).Where(a =>  a.IsActive).ToListAsync();


            // Count
            records.TotalRecords = skillRepository.GetSkillForGridCount(filter, true);

            records.CurrentPage = page;
            records.PageSize = pageSize;

            return View(records);
        }
```

but i will get the following error on the view:-

> HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous
>   operation to complete.    Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException:
>   HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous
>   operation to complete.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 172: Line 173:     Line
>   174:@Html.Action("Index", "Skill") Line 175:
>
> Line 176:
>   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.StaffID }) |

Comment: does it work you don't use mvc grid helper

Comment: @qamar now i modify my Html.Action to call an action method that return a simple html table instead of WebGrid but unfortunately i got the same error,, could this be that the Html.Action is calling async action method!!?

Comment: As per some researc Html.Action click considered as child action which is supported in aysnc mode. https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/601