# HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete for Social Providers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await, partial-views, httpserverutility

As Asked [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467185/httpserverutility-execute-blocked-while-waiting-for-an-asynchronous-operation-to), [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079613/html-action-is-raising-httpserverutility-execute-blocked-while-waiting-for-an) from other users but there is no any proper answer got so I asked here.

I am using ASP.NET MVC and trying to load social logins providers by partial view.

But I can't it gives me an error.

[image]

This is my code from where I return my partial view:

```
 public async Task<PartialViewResult> GetProviders()
        {
            string apiUrl = "mywebsite";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("Account/externalloginpathhere");
                //var result = Task.Run(async () => { await client.GetAsync("Account/externalloginpathhere"); }).Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var providers = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ViewModel>>(data);

                    foreach(var provider in providers)
                    {
                        if (provider.Name == "Google")
                        {
                            //code come here
                        }
                        else if (provider.Name == "Facebook")
                        {
                            //code come here
                        }
                        else if (provider.Name == "Microsoft")
                        {
                            //code come here
                        }
                    }
                    return PartialView("~/Views/Account/_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml", providers);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

View calling from Home Controller View:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("GetProviders", "Account");}
```

This is what I have done please correct me whereever I goes wrong!

Comment: have you found any answer on this?

Comment: @batmaci I have just posted the answer please refer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just figured it out don't know correct or not but I got the solution hope it helps someone.

I have just created one **partial view** and bind that partialview inside the page where I want login or signup process.

**Bind the partial view**:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Account/_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml")
```

**External Providers Partial View**:

```
 @{
    var loginProviders = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalAuthenticationTypes();
    if (loginProviders.Count() >= 0)
            {
             using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "externalLogin" }))
             {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                 <ul>
                   @foreach (var p in loginProviders)
                   {
                      <li>
                         <button value="@p.Caption" title="Login using @p.Caption account" name="provider" id="@p.Caption.ToLower()" type="submit" class="social-button">
                             <i class="fa fa-@p.Caption.ToLower()" id="@p.Caption"></i> 
                         </button>
                     </li>
                   }
                 </ul>
                }
             }
}
```